# Preprocessing text so that two words without a separating space (or hyphen separated) are detected

Tags: text, replace, data-cleaning

Let's say I have a text corpus with inconsistently written bi-grams. An example would be "bi gram", "bi-gram", "bigram". Is there any standard text preprocessing method to normalize all these as the same thing? i.e. replace all such occurrences by "bigram". I should also mention that I have no prior knowledge of what exact bi-grams  are present in the corpus.

Another thing I'm curious about - spell correction of standard words like common nouns is easy. But what about spell correction of proper nouns? I'm assuming that the correct spelling occurs more frequently than the incorrect spelling - so maybe I have a pandas series of text, in which majority of the rows contains "California", but there are some occurrences of "Califonria" as well.